# Microsoft form multiple choice depending on the availability

Tags: power-automate

I have a Microsoft Form that has a field for first name, one for last name and one question that has multiple choice (the user can select as many as he wants from this question) but, every person from this question has a limited number of seats available (from 1 to 5 depending from person to person)

First name: ...
Last name: ...
Which people do you choose to enrol?
1 - Man 1
2 - Man 2
3 - Women 3
4 - Women 4
5 - Women 5

Can I display the seats available in real time? How can I create the flow using power automate?

Example:
User 1:
First name: aaa
Last name: bbb
Which people do you choose to enrol?
1 - Man 1 needs to be displayed 4 seats available
2 - Man 2 needs to be displayed 3 seats available
3 - Women 3 needs to be displayed 2 seats available
4 - Women 4 needs to be displayed 5 seats available
5 - Women 5 needs to be displayed 1 seat available

He is choosing 1, 3, 5.
His response needs to be stored somewhere in Sharepoint.

Then for User 2:
First name: ccc
Last name: ddd
Which people do you choose to enrol?
1 - Man 1 needs to be displayed **3** seats available
2 - Man 2 needs to be displayed 3 seats available
3 - Women 3 needs to be displayed **1** seats available
4 - Women 4 needs to be displayed 5 seats available
5 - Women 5 needs to be displayed **0** seat available

an so on until all the seats are fully booked.

How can I do this using Microsoft Form and the flow using Power Automate?
Thank you!